# JRockit jmxmp support

Tags: jmx, jrockit, jmxmp

I am trying to use JRockit 5.2(that ships with JDK7u51)ito connect with MBean Server thru JMXMP connector but I am not able to add jmxmp connector support for JRocket. When I try to connect, JRockit tells me unsupported protocol.

Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the `jmxremote_optional.jar` in your classpath. `V4.0` was released in May 2013 and is here:

[jmxremote_optional](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.main.external/jmxremote_optional-repackaged)